# SQL - How to select all records not available at time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in a database which contains multiple records for some items: ITEMID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO. What I am trying to do is select all records not valid within a given date range (FRDATE, TODATE) - for more clarity I want to know which itemid is not valid from the end of todate (23:59:59).

Here sample data:

```
ITEMID    |VALIDFROM           |VALIDTO
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |01/01/2024 00:00:00 |02/01/2024 23:59:59
1         |04/01/2024 00:00:00 |10/01/2024 23:59:59
1         |15/01/2024 00:00:00 | null      (null means no expiration date)
2         |30/12/2023 00:00:00 |02/01/2024 23:59:59
3         |31/12/2023 00:00:00 | null      (null means no expiration date)
4         |30/12/2023 00:00:00 |03/01/2024 23:59:59
5         |03/01/2024 01:00:00 |03/01/2024 02:00:00
6         |02/01/2024 00:00:00 |03/01/2024 01:59:59
6         |03/01/2024 02:00:00 |03/01/2024 23:59:59
```

I expect these when FRDATE = 03/01/2024 00:00:00 and TODATE = 03/01/2024 23:59:59:

```
ITEMID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
2
4
5
6
```

Comment: please explain the logic, why itemid=2 is there as expected output

Comment: Please add what you have tried as a solution.

Comment: @User12345 The logic is already in the question "What I am trying to do is select all records not valid within a given date range" and since `ItemId` of `2` does not have a valid range that overlaps when `FRDATE` is `03/01/2024 00:00:00` and `TODATE` is `03/01/2024 23:59:59` then it should be in the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean return ID's having _no rows at all within_ the given range, or return ID's having _one or more rows outside_ the given range?

Comment: @jarlh Your second option does not make sense for the question "select all records not valid within a given date range" as if you had one `itemid` that was valid from `2024-01-01` to `2024-01-10` and also valid from `2024-01-21` to `2024-01-30` and you were looking for items that were not valid on `2024-01-05` then it would not be correct to include that item just because there is "one or more rows outside the given range" because it is valid for the given range even if the range `2024-01-21` to `2024-01-30` does not overlap the desired range.

Comment: @MTO, I know. I'm waiting for OP to clarify.

Comment: If you had the data `itemid=5, validfrom=2024-01-03, validto=2024-01-04` and `frdate=2024-01-01, todate=2024-01-10` then would you expect that to be excluded from the result as the item is valid for part of the range or excluded from the result as the item is not valid for the entirety of the range (only for part of the range)?

Comment: I am so sorry for late reply. I edited the topic for more clarity. So sorry!

Comment: @MTO, so sorry and thank you for your supporting. The data ```itemid=9, validfrom=2024-01-03, validto=2024-01-04 and frdate=2024-01-01, todate=2024-01-10```, sorry I haven't thought about this. From my expectation, I want this data to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING` clause with conditional aggregation to check whether the ranges overlaps with the bounds you are checking.

#### Option 1: If an `itemid` is considered valid when any part of the desired range overlaps:

```sql
SELECT itemid
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN validfrom <= DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
         AND  (  validto IS NULL
              OR validto >= DATE '2024-01-03'
              )
         THEN 1
         END
       ) = 0
```

#### Option 2: If an `itemid` is considered valid only when the entirety of the desired range overlaps:

```sql
SELECT itemid
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN validfrom <= DATE '2024-01-03'
         AND  (  validto IS NULL
              OR validto >= DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
              )
         THEN 1
         END
       ) = 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ITEMID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-01', DATE '2024-01-02' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-04', DATE '2024-01-10' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2024-01-15', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-12-30', DATE '2024-01-02' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATE '2023-12-31', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATE '2023-12-30', DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Both outputs:

| ITEMID |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 1 |

But if there was an additional row:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (ITEMID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO)
VALUES (5, DATE '2023-01-03' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '2' HOUR);
```

Then:

- The first query would exclude that row as there is a valid range partially within the desired range and just return `1,2`; and
- The second query would include that row as there is not a valid range that covers the entirety of the desired range and would return `1,2,5`.

---

#### Clarification to Option 2: If the desired range is entirely covered by multiple consecutive partial ranges

If you may have multiple consecutive ranges and the desired range will be entirely matched but over two-or-more distinct consecutive valid ranges such as:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (ITEMID, VALIDFROM, VALIDTO)
SELECT 6, DATE '2024-01-02', DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '01:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '2' HOUR, DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Then the 1st query will still work if you want to consider the desired range matched if there is any partial match. However, the second query would not work for this edge-case; instead, you would need to merge the consecutive ranges first using (from Oracle 12) `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` and then apply the previous logic:

```sql
SELECT itemid
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY itemid
         ORDER BY validfrom
         MEASURES
           FIRST(validfrom) AS validfrom,
           LAsT(validto) AS validto
         PATTERN (consecutive* last_row)
         DEFINE
           consecutive AS validto + INTERVAL '1' SECOND = NEXT(validfrom)
       )
GROUP BY itemid
HAVING COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN validfrom <= DATE '2024-01-03'
         AND  (  validto IS NULL
              OR validto >= DATE '2024-01-03' + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND
              )
         THEN 1
         END
       ) = 0
```

Which outputs `1,2,5`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mo1XNw0A)

Answer (score 0):

If your whole FRDATE till TODATE period should be between VALIDFROM and VALIDTO then you can use simple NOT BETWEEN for both FRDATE and TODATE with OR operator. For nulls use Nvl() with the date far away in the future...
Select ITEMID either with the Distinct or Group By...

```sql
WITH     --  S a m p l e   D a t a :
    tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ITEMID", DATE '2024-01-01' "VALIDFROM", TO_DATE('2024-01-02 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "VALIDTO" From Dual Union All
          Select 1 "ITEMID", DATE '2024-01-04' "VALIDFROM", TO_DATE('2024-01-10 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "VALIDTO" From Dual Union All
          Select 1 "ITEMID", DATE '2024-01-15' "VALIDFROM", Null "VALIDTO" From Dual Union All
          Select 2 "ITEMID", DATE '2023-12-30' "VALIDFROM", TO_DATE('2024-01-02 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "VALIDTO" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ITEMID", DATE '2023-12-11' "VALIDFROM", Null "VALIDTO" From Dual Union All
          Select 4 "ITEMID", DATE '2023-12-30' "VALIDFROM", TO_DATE('2024-01-03 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "VALIDTO" From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
-- M a i n   S Q L :
Select  Distinct ITEMID
From    tbl
Where   TO_DATE('2024-01-03 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') NOT BETWEEN VALIDFROM And Nvl(VALIDTO, DATE '2062-10-11') OR
        TO_DATE('2024-01-03 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') NOT BETWEEN VALIDFROM And Nvl(VALIDTO, DATE '2062-10-11')
-- OR --->  Group By ITEMID  <--- instead of Distinct
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t :
    ITEMID
----------
         1
         2  */
```

On the opposite side if validity of a row should be completely within FRDATE till TODATE period then you can also use NOT BETWEEN for both VALIDFROM and VALIDTO but with AND operator...

```sql
-- M a i n   S Q L    2 :
Select  Distinct ITEMID
From    tbl
Where   VALIDFROM NOT BETWEEN TO_DATE('2024-01-03 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') And TO_DATE('2024-01-03 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND
        Nvl(VALIDTO, DATE '2062-10-11') NOT BETWEEN  TO_DATE('2024-01-03 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') And TO_DATE('2024-01-03 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
-- OR --->  Group By ITEMID  <--- instead of Distinct
```

... the result is not as expected in question

```sql
/*  R e s u l t :
    ITEMID
----------
         1
         2
         3  */
```

Additionaly, if you are asking for any kind of partial overlaping then you should explain it and adjust your sample data and expected result to match the logic. Anyway, whatever it is I'm pretty sure it could be solved using multiple BETWEEN or NOT BETWEEN conditions with And/Or operators...

Comment: This gives a false positive when a valid range is completely contained in the date range [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yBa5xVh3).

Comment: @MTO, the question isn't very clear. _select all records not valid within a given date range_ and the desired result don't match.

Comment: @MT0 Not clear what OP wants. Thats why I put "if whole period...". And if that is the case then your answer misses it in case that for ITEMID=4 the VALIDTO is ... 23:59:58. See it here https://dbfiddle.uk/C0wtkJK6

Comment: @dr The example in your previous comment *should* have `itemid=4` excluded if you "select all records not valid within a given date range" because it is valid from 2024-01-03 00:00:00 to 2024-01-03 23:59:58 which partially overlaps the given date range of 2024-01-03 00:00:00 to 2024-01-03 23:59:59 so it is a record that is valid within the given range and the OP only wants items that are not valid. So from that perspective, my answer is correct and `itemid=4` should be excluded.

Comment: @MTO Once again: If whole FRDATE till TODATE period should be between validity period of the row then your answer isn't correct, but it depends on what OP realy want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use range comparison and negate it as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITEMID
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE
    NOT ( VALIDFROM BETWEEN DATE '2024-01-03' 
                        AND TO_DATE('2024-01-03 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        OR DATE '2024-01-03' BETWEEN VALIDFROM 
                                 AND COALESCE(VALIDTO, DATE '9999-12-31') )
```